# Esperar um determinado período para executar uma função em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Existe algum método que faça uma função executar depois de um determinado tempo?
O que preciso é que a função abaixo execute depois de um período de tempo, pois o ID que ela busca só fica disponível depois de um tempo em que ficamos na pagina.

```js
var func = document.getElementById('olvideo_html5_api').src;
alert(func);
window.location.href = +func
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` para executar uma função após o tempo especificado (em segundos):

```
tempo = 10; //especifique aqui os segundos
tempo = tempo*1000;
setTimeout(function(){
    var func = document.getElementById('olvideo_html5_api').src;
    alert(func);
    window.location.href = func;
}, tempo);
```

**Ou** você pode especificar o tempo diretamente na função:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var func = document.getElementById('olvideo_html5_api').src;
    alert(func);
    window.location.href = func;
}, 10000); // o tempo é dado em milisegundos
```

Comment: A função de capturar o ID funcionou perfeitamente, porém não conseguiu redirecionar o site para o link capturado.

Comment: O primeiro método é mais interessante por causa do seu conversor de segundo em milissegundos.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz Seu erro estava em `window.location.href = +func;`... Veja a correção que fiz na resposta: `window.location.href = func;`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, eu achava que em toda manipulação de link com variável se fazia necessário o "+" antes da mesma.